# Passing Bash array to Python script

Tags: bash, python

I am having problem in sending bash array `problem_list` to python script `update_contest.py`. Here is my code :

bash file :

```
echo $problems
declare -a problem_list
for i in $problems;
do
    problem_list+=($i)
done
echo ${problem_list[@]}
python3 update_contest.py $id ${problem_list[@]}
```

python file:

```
id = (sys.argv)[1]
problem_list = (sys.argv)[2]
print(problem_list)
```

output in terminal :

```
A B C D E
A B C D E
A
```

As can be seen, only A is passed as argument in problem_list.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are indexing the list of arguments with 2, so only returning its second element, which is the first argument.

Replace this line `problem_list = (sys.argv)[2]` with `problem_list = sys.argv[2:-1]`.

https://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html

Comment: Thanks a lot ! it worked. Actually I thought I need to send array as single argument. But, this approach also worked.

Comment: @PratikKale You can't pass any real data structure as an argument to a unix program; the arguments are just strings, so to "pass an array" you turn it into a list of strings and pass each of those strings as a separate argument. BTW, the safe way to do this is `"${problem_list[@]}"` -- the double-quotes prevent the shell from trying to parse the array elements, and mangling them in the process. Putting double-quotes around variable references in the shell is almost always a good idea.